# swift custom NSURLProtocol error

Tags: ios, swift

**I want to load remote url and use local resources(image,css,js...), so I inherit NSURLProtocol.**

```
import Foundation

class MyURLProtocol: NSURLProtocol {

    override class func canInitWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> Bool {
        print(request.URL!.absoluteString)
        if request.URL!.absoluteString.hasSuffix("jquery.min.js"){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    override class func canonicalRequestForRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> NSURLRequest{
        let urlPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jquery.min", ofType: "js", inDirectory:"res/js")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(urlPath!)
        let mutableReqeust = request.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
        mutableReqeust.URL = url
        return mutableReqeust
    }
}
```

**register new url protocol in AppDelegate**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    NSURLProtocol.registerClass(MyURLProtocol)
    return true
}
```

**my resources directory structure**

```
res
└── js
    └── jquery.min.js
```

*when code is running ,the error as follow*

```
    0x111785900 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x111785901 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x111785904 <+4>:   pushq  %rbx
    0x111785905 <+5>:   pushq  %rax
    0x111785906 <+6>:   movq   %rdi, %rbx
    0x111785909 <+9>:   movq   0x118(%rbx), %rdi
->  0x111785910 <+16>:  movq   0x368(%rdi), %rax  [WebThread(7):EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1.address=0x368)].
    0x111785917 <+23>:  movq   %rax, 0x508(%rbx)
```

**I input continue many times with lldb, but code stays in 0x111785910**

**What's wrong with code ?**

Comment: Something was probably nil - you haven't given enough information.  What line of *your* code did it crash on?  What other messages appeared on the console?

Comment: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/login.jsp?title=no

    http://xx.xx.xx.xx/login.jsp?title=no

    http://xx.xx.xx.xx/login.jsp?title=no

    http://xx.xx.xx.xx/login.jsp?title=no

    http://xx.xx.xx.xx/login.jsp?title=no

    http://xx.xx.xx.xx/js/ustc.js

    http://xx.xx.xx.xx/js/jquery.min.js

    (lldb) continue

    Process 15696 resuming

    (lldb) continue

    Process 15696 resuming
    
    (lldb)

Comment: You need to look in the stack trace and look at which line in your code it is throwing the exception on.  Or set breakpoints and step through your code and see where it crashes.

Comment: Thanks，I'm going to try

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution and I write a blog as follows 。
http://codeboy.me/2015/09/25/ios-uiwebview-optimization/